# Library for creating simple 3D models like SketchUp

Tags: java, web-services, model, 3d

I`m looking for a programming library for creating 3d models like the attached graphic.

It is for a web-application written in Java, but I am open to all suggestions (as long as the model is generated at the back-end/server-side of the application).

There is no need for "live rotation" of the models, I only need to generate some sort of image files from 2-3 different angles.

Any suggestions?

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use server-side scripting to create models in SketchUp.  [Shade Shelters Toolbox](http://www.shadeshelterstoolbox.com) is a site doing this with PHP and AJAX.  The Ruby scripts SketchUp uses could be stored in a database for common parts, or they could be generated based on selected parameters.